# Matplotlib: Unsure how to set new x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using `matplotlib` to graph the relationship between a variable `N` and some `Y` values.  Here's my code:

```
plt.title("My Graph")
plt.xlabel("Values of N")
plt.ylabel("Estimated Y Values")
plt.plot(predictions)
plt.show()
```

And I get:

[image]

This is great, except for the x-axis labels.  My `predictions` list has 5 values in it, corresponding to values of `N = 10, N = 20, N = 40, N = 80, N = 160`.

How can I change the x-axis to reflect this (so the first Y value is directly above `N = 10`, second Y values i directly above `N = 20`, etc)?  I do want to keep the interpolation between data points, so I don't want a scatterplot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`plt.plot(x, y)` accepts two parameters, as shown.  try:

`x = [10, 20, 40, 80, 160]
plt.plot(x, predictions)`

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html